# Can't plot g[x] in Manipulate

Tags: manipulate

Where did I get wrong?

Even adding `Evaluate@` before g[x] can't solve this mess.

```
f[x_] /; x < 0 := Abs[x + 1];
f[x_] /; 0 < x := Log[x];
g[x_] := x^2 - 4 x + 1 + 2 \[Lambda];
Manipulate[
 Plot[{g[x], f[x]}, {x, -30, 30}, PlotRange -> 10 {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, 
  AspectRatio -> 1, PlotStyle -> {Gray, Orange}, 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
  PlotLegends -> {"f", "g"}], {{\[Lambda], 0, "Lambda"}, -2, 2, 1/10}]
```

Comment: That's because `Manipulate` does no like to update hidden parmeters. Try `g[x_,\[Lambda]_] := x^2 - 4 x + 1 + 2 \[Lambda];` and  `[...] Plot[{g[x,\[Lambda]], f[x]}, [...]`.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, Is it possible to remove the vertical line `x=0`, I didn't set what the value is when x=0. But Mathematica automatically connect this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
f[x_] /; x < 0 := Abs[x + 1];
f[x_] /; 0 < x := Log[x];
g[x_, \[Lambda]_] := x^2 - 4 x + 1 + 2 \[Lambda];

Manipulate[
 Plot[
  {g[x, \[Lambda]], f[x]}, {x, -30, 30},
  PlotRange -> 10 {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
  PlotStyle -> {Gray, Orange},
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", PlotLegends -> {"f", "g"}],
 {{\[Lambda], 0, "Lambda"}, -2, 2, 1/10},
 TrackedSymbols :> {\[Lambda]}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

without the y-axis:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[{g[x, \[Lambda]], f[x]}, {x, -30, 30}, Exclusions -> None, 
  PlotRange -> 10 {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
  Axes -> {True, False},
  PlotStyle -> {Gray, Orange}, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
  PlotLegends -> {"f", "g"}], {{\[Lambda], 0, "Lambda"}, -2, 2, 1/10},
 TrackedSymbols :> {\[Lambda]}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Is it possible to remove the vertical line `x=0`, I didn't set what the value is when x=0. But Mathematica automatically connect this point.

Comment: Maybe by setting the `Exclusions` option in `Plot`?

Comment: @kile you mean remove the y-axis? If so, updated.

Comment: @Nasser, nope, Just get rid of `x=0`

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, `Exclusions` works great.